# Drag and drop 3 different images inside a div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am able to try to drag and drop multiple images into a same div which is under a .
There will be an initial value for each image and those many images will be present inside the div. When we drag and drop any image it should add that image with the existing images inside the div.

I tried drag and drop for 2 images.
First image is shown in div with the initial value and when I drag drop the second image it works fine. Again if i Try to drop first image all the 2nd images dropped in the div changes to 1st image.
I want to save the number of different images dropped inside a div without replacing the existing images with the current image that has been dropped.

I tried the following condition

(condition1 ? img1 : (condition2 ? img1 : img2));

I am trying to do with conditional statement.

Also I am saving the number of images dropped into a state.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .droppable {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            border: 2px dashed #ccc;
        }
        img {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            margin: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="droppable" id="dropArea">
        <!-- Images will be added here -->
    </div>

    <script>
        const dropArea = document.getElementById('dropArea');
        const state = {};

        // Add a dragover event listener to allow dropping.
        dropArea.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        // Add a drop event listener to handle the dropped items.
        dropArea.addEventListener('drop', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];

            // Check if the file is an image.
            if (file.type.startsWith('image/')) {
                const imgUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);

                // Check if the image URL is already in the state.
                if (!state[imgUrl]) {
                    state[imgUrl] = 1; // Initialize count for this image URL.
                } else {
                    state[imgUrl]++; // Increment the count for this image URL.
                }

                // Update the HTML content of the div based on the state.
                updateDivContent();
            }
        });

        // Function to update the HTML content of the div based on the state.
        function updateDivContent() {
            dropArea.innerHTML = '';

            for (const imgUrl in state) {
                const imgCount = state[imgUrl];
                const img = new Image();
                img.src = imgUrl;
                img.alt = `Image ${imgCount}`;
                dropArea.appendChild(img);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

To achieve your goal of allowing users to drag and drop multiple images into a  while maintaining the count of different images dropped without replacing existing images with the current image that has been dropped, you can follow these steps:

Maintain a state to keep track of the images dropped and their counts.
When a new image is dropped, check if it's already in the . If it's not present, add it to the state and update the count. If it's already present, do nothing.
Update the HTML content of the  based on the state to display the images and their counts.

Comment: OP is using react